# Javascript regular expression to check whether a string is a combination of certain character

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to check if a string starting from `-` i.e. `hypen` followed by any combination of the 3 characters i.e. `a`, `p` or `m`.

For example: `-a , -p , -ap,-am,-apm` etc.

Please help.

Comment: Please also share what you have tried so far.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please visit the [help] and read about how to write good questions on SO.

Comment: Hi i don't know much about regular expression,so posted this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following `regex`. This will check if the `str` starts with `-` and followed by any one of the `a`, `p` or `m` in any sequence having at least one character and maximum of three characters.

```
/^-[apm]{1,3}$/.test(str)
```

**Regex Explanation**

1. `/`: Delimiter of `regex`
2. `^-`: Starts with `-`
3. `[apm]`: Matches any characters inside `[]` in any sequence
4. `{1,3}`: Matches preceding set of characters in the range from 1 to 3
5. `$` : End of the match